# Duplicate records in MySQL. EXISTS check for the same data not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, duplicates

```
SELECT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE deleted_at IS NULL and the_date = '$the_date' AND company_name = '$company_name' AND purchase_country = '$p_country' AND lot = '$lot_no') AS numofrecords")
```

What is wrong with this mysql query? 
It is still allowing duplicates inserts (1 out of 1000 records). Around 100 users making entries, so the traffic is not that big, I assume. I do not have access to the database metrics, so I can not be sure.

Comment: If this is an SQL question, just give us the query and some details about the database. Remove the PHP and fix the tags!

Comment: It's possible that two users could execute the `SELECT` at the same time and get a 0 result, and then both do the insert. You should look into table locks.

Comment: I think you're mistaken `EXISTS` with `distinct`


https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp


try using `SELECT DISTINCT` instead

Comment: @Nick your comment gave me the clue and I found the solution. Thanks to you and everyone else who responded now I understand that it is in fact possible for MySQL to mix one user`s data with others`, if they made it at the same time. One positive response from the EXISTS check could indeed allow wrong data to slip in.

Comment: @dprojects2050 Glad to hear you found a solution. If you think it might be useful to other users, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Nick gave the clues to solve the issue. Separated `EXIST` check and `INSERT` was not the best way. Two users were actually able to do `INSERT`, if one got 0. A single statement query with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The EXISTS condition is use in a WHERE clause. In your case, the first select doesn't specify the table and the condition.

One example:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM order_details
              WHERE customers.customer_id = order_details.customer_id);
```

Try to put your statement like this, and if it returns the data duplicated, just use a DISTINCT. (`SELECT DISCTINCT * .....`)

Comment: The table is specified with variable. There are two tables in two databases with similar setup, so using a variable was an option.

`INSERT INTO table columns VALUES () ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `

solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for you :

```
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY your_column_want_to_dupplicate);
```